# Expected stack to be an array at sanitize

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error when I created my expo project of react-native.

in the debugging window it shows this
[image]

when I hover the error message it says error generated at sanitize.
I don't know what to do, I just created the very first project and didn't even changed a single line.

All though the app is working, it's like I when I run the application it is working fine and every component is loading correctly but after few seconds of load, this error pop ups.

Any idea how to deal with it or is it really necessary to fix it (I think any error can make application to crash in future so maybe it is good to fix it )

Comment: Where is maybeStack instantiated?